# Re-render output HTML in ASP.NET VB 4.5 Webforms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to rewrite the final output of a .NET VB Masterfile to move all `<script>` elements to the foot of the page (pre the `</body>` tag) before the render is sent to the browser?

Comment: You can write an http module to process the HTML but I doubt it will perform well. Better just move the scripts to the bottom especially if it is a master page file.

Comment: Can't you just move it in the master page?